# Install gksu on Centos

Tags: linux, centos, centos-5

I want to install `gksu` on Centos 5.5. `su` and `sudo` both work fine (although I had to tweak some BASH profile files to find the commands properly), but I want `gksu` installed so that I can easily use root privileges for `nautilus` without having to open a terminal or login as root. I've searched for `gksu` in the default Centos repositories, but haven't found anything. Is there a `gksu` package available for Centos? If so, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["How to run a program from GNOME menu with root privileges"](http://fedoranews.org/contributors/matt_hansen/nautilus/)

Comment: That was more work than I was expecting, but it definitely works.